# Upgrading to Access 2010 - what does one need to buy for pro development and distribution?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I use Access 2000 at the moment with a Sagekey Access 2000 MSI Wizard.

For the ability to distribute my app as a runtime I had to buy the Office 2000 Professional software.  I then realised for effective and reliable installation I had to buy the Sagekey runtime.

This all works well.

Lately I feel I could benefit from the features of a later version of Access.  I can't seem to find info on what I need to buy specifically to put myself in the same position as I am now (shipping MDEs with a Sagekey installer to customers) but using Access 2010 instead.

Can I just buy Access 2010 on it's own these days?  I'm checking with Sagekey about support for Access 2010 as it doesn't appear to be listed on their site - Access 2007 is the latest there - but of course Access 2007 seems a bit like an endangered species so I think I should avoid that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a licensing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the Access 2000 days, the developer kit and extensions was quite expensive for Access and was a SEPERATE purchase. And as you found out, you still needed to purchase a commercial installer like sagekey. Having to purchase both was quite expensive.

Today, the developer kit and runtime system for Access 2010 is free. However, that system still ships with a very weak install and setup system that tends to cause problems if the end user has other versions of Access installed. So, once again, your best bet is sagekey.

There is a buy now button on their page that shows 2007, but if you click on the order tab a 2010 version is also available.

So at least the runtime is free for Access, and is included for the basic price of Access. This does reduce the cost of this system overall.

Comment: I don't think the old developer's tools were all that expensive. A few hundred dollars that allow you to deploy on an unlimited number of PCs does not seem to me like a large expense at all.

Comment: I much agree, it not that expensive when the need justifies the purchase. I remember companies paying $500 for word perfect, and then the spell checker was a 3rd party purchase and add in.  And after so many years, it still nice to see Access continues to have a runtime option.